# Does “Marvel Universe” mean just Earth-616, or the whole multiverse?

Tags: marvel, comics

EDIT:I'm just confused how to properly use the term. I understand that each alternate universes have it's own designation numbers but just wondering whether the term 'Marvel Universe' simply just mean the main universe which is 616 or it could be use to referred to the whole multiverse(main universe + all the alternate universes) as well?

Comment: Everyones "Marvel Universe" is likely to be different. For some it will just be the comics, others the movies, other the TV side etc.. In *general* though the "Universe" is the Multiverse which includes **all** of it.

Comment: If a specific Marvel Universe is in question, it is usually designated with an Earth-[NUMBER] designation. If you are dealing with the mainstream canon Marvel Universe, it will be designated Earth-616. Other Earths, or participants from other Earths in the Marvel Multiverse get designations placed on them by the publisher. The Marvel Cinematic Universe is designated: Earth-199999.